# Passing data from the view to the controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, variable-assignment

In my app, user can upload a list of car entries with xml. The uploaded entries are then displayed, giving the user the possibility to choose the cars that are to be saved in the database. the unsaved entries should be displayed again, giving the user the possibility to select more or discard accordingly.

I am doing this now by setting the entries from the controller to the view, saving these entries in a hidden field as a json string, and when the user selects the entries, they are deserialized into arrays and saved in the database.

The question now is if this is a good practice, or if there could be a better way of doing this?

Thanks,
Roland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem in doing that the way you are doing. But you could use the session to store this temporarily data too.

Comment: I must have been dreaming these past few days. I cannot believe I did not think of the session. Thanks.